# Finding coordinates of two intersecting circle

Tags: trigonometry, circles, intersection-theory

I have coordinates of two points *P1* and *P2* and the radius of circle *R* and what I need, is to find coordinates of two posible circle centers *S1* and *S2*.

[example intersecting circle](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/IpdtpkKms4AafdrizTlsYyxD8Ts7C8xmsnvAiwA2QxK5-0caXh0b0B-aASKoRhZ2ZMu3c7dHt1FjWgI=w1920-h1021)

When I'm trying to use

> (X-Xo)^2+(Y-Yo)^2=R^2

I'm getting something like this

> Y^2(1+(P1x-P2x)^2/(P1y-P2y)^2)+ y((P1x-P2x)^2/4+(P1x-P2x)^2/(P1y-P2y)^2)+R^2+1/(P1x-P2x)^2+(P1x-P2x)^2/4+(P1y-P2y)^2/4

When I'm trying to use vectors I'm getting something similarly long and none of my equations gives proper values.

I know that there have to be some smart solution but I can't find it. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centers will lie on the perpendicular bisector of the line segment joining the intersection points. Use the Pythagorean theorem to find the distance of those centers from the midpoint of that line segment.

That said, the system of equations that you’ve set up isn’t all *that* long or difficult. Try solving it directly—it builds character.

Comment: Helo
 
Problem loocks easy but it isn't. for example Wolfram gives the following solutions:
 
[example1](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%28x-a%29%5E2%2B%28y-b%29%5E2-r%5E2%3D0%2F%2F%5D%2C%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%28x-c%29%5E2%2B%28y-d%29%5E2-r%5E2%3D0%2F%2F%5D+for+x%2Cy&x=8&y=11) and [example2](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%28b-a%29x%2B%28d-c%29y%3D0%2F%2F%5D%2C%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Asqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29-r%5E2%2Be%2F4%3D0%2F%2F%5D+for+x%2Cy&x=10&y=7)
 
Question: Is there exist **short** solution ?

Comment: @DawidD No, the problem is rather simple. Why don’t you try it for yourself again instead of relying on online equation solvers? If you can’t handle a pair of quadratics, then reduce the degree of the equations by using the geometric facts in my answer. You can, for instance, reduce this problem to one of finding the intersection of a line and a circle.

Comment: @DawidD If, on the other hand, you’re looking for a short *expression* for the coordinates in terms of the coordinates of the given points, you’re not likely to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Helo
You can find answer by finding vector that points center of circle from the point between the P1 and P2. This vector will be perpendicular to the vector that links points.

If you make following variable substitution, you get short expresion for the vector.

a=P2x-P1x

b=P2y-P1y

[solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%5B%2F%2Fmath:+ax%2Bby%3D0%2F%2F%5D,%5B%2F%2Fmath:++x%5E2%2By%5E2+-r%5E2%2Ba%5E2%2F4%2Bb%5E2%2F4%3D0%2F%2F%5D+for+x,y)

S1x=P1x+a/2+x(of vector)

S1y=P1y+b/2+y(of vector)

There are two solutions so second is for S2.